# D3 hide .text element from node

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I got a forced directed graph with certain nodes. Further I append icon´s as *.text* which contains icons from fontawesome. I am struggling to hide those icons with an .on("click") event. I am able to hide the selected node but the icon is still there. Any Idea?

I tried it with .text("visibility", "hidden") and also with ".style("font-size", "0px") etc. I could change the css but I do not want to remove all icon´s just those I select.

[image]

```
var icon = svg.selectAll("svg")
            .data(data_nodes)
            .enter()
                //.append("g")
                .append("text")
                .attr("id", "nodeTooltip")
                .attr("class", "icon")
                .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                .attr("dominant-baseline", "central")
                .style("font-family","FontAwesome")
                .style("font-size","30px")
                .text(function (d) {return d.icon;})
                .call(d3.drag()
                    .on("start", dragStarted)
                    .on("drag", dragged)
                    .on("end", dragEnded)
                )
                 // disable browser context menu on icon
                .on("contextmenu", function (d, i){
                    d3.event.preventDefault()
                })
                .on("mouseenter", function(d) {
                    d3.event.preventDefault()
                })

function click(d) {
    if (boolOpacity == true) {
        nodes.filter((n) => {
            return n.parent == d.id
        }).style("visibility", "hidden")
        .text("visibility", "hidden")
        })
                boolOpacity = false
    } else {
        nodes.filter((n) => {
            return n.parent == d.id
        }).style("visibility", "visible")
        boolOpacity = true
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it! I doubt I got the "perfect" solution but it is working. Beside adding the nodes and the related JSON file I also created a own icons value with the same JSON data as for the nodes. For better references etc.

I simply forgot about and did filtered.

```
nodes.filter((n) => {
            icons.filter((m) => {
                return m.parent == d.id
            }).style("visibility", "hidden")
            return  n.parent == d.id 
        }).style("visibility", "hidden")
```